# vercel не видит файл

Tags: php, html, html-form

есть вот такая проблема что у нас vercel не видит check.php перепробовал всё что можно!

https://php-project-5qty8jrdl-vitaluska123.vercel.app/

при отправке формы он не находит его...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**vercel.json:**

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [{ "src": "index.php", "use": "vercel-php@0.5.0" }],
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/check.php",
            "destination": "/check.php"
        }
    ]
}
```

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Links</title>
    <style type="css/stylesheat"> </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="search" action="/check.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="searchTxt" placeholder="Поиск">
        <input type="submit" name="go" value="Найти">
    </form>

    <?php
    require(__DIR__ . '/php/allVid.php');

    $json = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/vid/vid.json');
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    vidCount($obj);
    PrintVideo($obj);
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

при этом он в гитхабе есть и сборка на vercel последняя
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалась простым для всех файлов и тп роуты прописать:

`vercel.json`

```
{
    "functions": {
        "api/*.php": {
            "runtime": "vercel-php@0.5.0"
        }
    },
    "routes": [
        { "src": "/check", "dest": "/api/check.php" },
        { "src": "/style.css", "dest": "/styles/index.css" },
        { "src": "/styleCheck.css", "dest": "/styles/check.css" },
        { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/api/index.php" }
    ]
}
```